# How do I get awk to print fields from the second row of a file?

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
   measured      10.8       0.0000    0.0000    0.0236    0.0304    0.0383    0.0433    0.0437    0.0442    0.0452
                            0.0455    0.0448    0.0440    0.0423    0.0386    0.0344    0.0274    0.0000    0.0000
```

I want gawk to print all the numbers in one long single column like this:

```
0.0000
0.0000
0.0236
0.0304
0.0383
0.0433
0.0437
0.0442
0.0452
0.0455
0.0448
0.0440
0.0423
0.0386
0.0344
0.0274
0.0000
0.0000
```

I run the command `gawk '/measured/ { printf $3"\n" $4"\n" $5"\n" $6"\n" $7"\n" $8"\n" $9"\n" $10"\n" $11"\n" $12"\n" $13"\n" $14"\n" $15"\n" $16"\n" $17"\n" $18"\n" }' filename.txt`

But I just get the first row of numbers:

```
0.0000
0.0000
0.0236
0.0304
0.0383
0.0433
0.0437
0.0442
0.0452
```

How do I get gawk to print the second row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS = "\n" }
/measured/ { c=2; $1=$2=""; $0=$0 }
c && c-- { $1=$1; print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
0.0000
0.0000
0.0236
0.0304
0.0383
0.0433
0.0437
0.0442
0.0452
0.0455
0.0448
0.0440
0.0423
0.0386
0.0344
0.0274
0.0000
0.0000
```

Comment: If I were to run that as a batch file on multiple input files, how would I get it to insert a newline between each output? 

If I run BEGIN { OFS = "\n" }
/measured/ { c=2; $1=$2=""; $0=$0 }
c && c-- { $1=$1; print }
{print "\n"}

I end up getting:

0.0000
0.0000
0.1125
0.1440
0.1799
0.2024
0.2037
0.2062
0.2103


0.2115
0.2082
0.2046
0.1970
0.1803
0.1615
0.1297
0.0000
0.0000

It splits the column after each row, when I want it all in one column.

Comment: Sounds like you'd just want to add `ENDFILE{print ""}` if you have GNU awk BUT you can't post formatted text in a comment so I'm not sure what you're asking about (in particular I've no idea how to write a "batch file" - sounds Windows-y!) and [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are discouraged so please ask a new question with it;s own sample input/output if that's not what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -A1 measured file | tr -s ' ' \\n | tail -n+4

0.0000
0.0000
0.0236
0.0304
0.0383
0.0433
0.0437
0.0442
0.0452
0.0455
0.0448
0.0440
0.0423
0.0386
0.0344
0.0274
0.0000
0.0000
```

with `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS='\n' '/measured/ {p=1; for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $i; next}
                            p {$1=$1; print; exit}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of fields is guaranteed to be as in the example, you can use the following command:

```
awk '{for(i=NF-8;i<=NF;i++){print $i}}' input.file
```

Answer (score 0):

The GNU implementation of Awk allows an arbitrary regular expression as the `RS` record separator If the keyword `measured` occurs before each batch of numbers, we can use that keyword as the separator:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { RS = "measured" } { for (i = 1; i <= NF ; i++) print "field " i " = " $i }'
   measured      10.8       0.0000    0.0000    0.0236    0.0304    0.0383    0.0433    0.0437    0.0442    0.0452
                            0.0455    0.0448    0.0440    0.0423    0.0386    0.0344    0.0274    0.0000    0.000

field 1 = 10.8
field 2 = 0.0000
field 3 = 0.0000
field 4 = 0.0236
field 5 = 0.0304
field 6 = 0.0383
field 7 = 0.0433
field 8 = 0.0437
field 9 = 0.0442
field 10 = 0.0452
field 11 = 0.0455
field 12 = 0.0448
field 13 = 0.0440
field 14 = 0.0423
field 15 = 0.0386
field 16 = 0.0344
field 17 = 0.0274
field 18 = 0.0000
field 19 = 0.000
```

As you can see, all the fields between the `measured` record separators are parsed out regardless of line breaks. Fields are separated on any mixture of spaces, tabs and newlines.

Note that because `measured` appears first, we get an empty record. The output you see above is, effectively, from the second record. The first record is the whitespcae before `measured`, which contains no fields.

In other words, he record separator is really expected to be a terminator, except that it can be missing after the last record.